# How to deploy a token and put it on a DEX

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, solana-cli, metaplex-js

I just wanted to understand how I can create a real token and get it on an exchange. I was using the Solana Bootcamp presented by Nick Frosty as a basis but then I'm a bit confused on how to use the Solana CLI at that point (after I've made a few changes to the code), to get the coin on serum for example. Furthermore, is there a way to write up a smart contract simply using JS?

Comment: As an FYI, the usage Serum has completely been replaced by OpenBook after November 2022.

Comment: Thanks for the info I'm new to this and really have no idea yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i already made a tool to create / update metadata for Solana tokens, if you want i can add token creation and give you the url ?

if you want to do it by yourself, i advise that you take a look at that video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cn-HnG_yns&list=PLmAMfj0qP2wxlaDRjhjjo6b76s9k_ma5l very clear, a lot of things are explained

Comment: Thanks I'll watch the video, I want to get first hand experience on how to do it, but I am watching your video at the moment

Comment: the video is not from me ;) you can look on Andy's playlist, there are many videos to learn solana dev related stuff !